# Docker base image includes a volume. How can I stop mounting it in my derived image

Tags: docker

I have a docker base image that uses a volume and the base image is out of my control

For example: `VOLUME ["/my/path"]`

I'm trying to build a derived image that doesn't define a volume. I want the data in /my/path to be transient and never persisted.

Is there a way I can disable a volume that came from a parent container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a great feature, unfortunately it seems like the Docker team has de-prioritized it. Refer to: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465

For now, Docker copy edit may be your best option depending on your use case. https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to negate the `VOLUME` instruction from a parent image. You'd have to rebuild the parent image.