# mongo docker images creates 2 volumes when using docker-compose even with volumes set

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Currently running WSL Ubuntu and Docker Desktop on my Windows host. When I run a docker-compose.yaml on my wsl for mongo and mongo-express, even if I defined a volume and mounted the mongo data path, it seems to create 2 volumes, the one I declared, and another anonymous one. Everything else runs as normal. I do not know why this happens, can anyone help?

yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGSSg.png)

I have tried changing the way the volume is declared in the file, to a windows path, to directly mapping it, etc. No luck

Comment: While this question is answerable without the image content, please [make sure to include error messages as plain text directly in the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) in the future.

Comment: @DavidMaze hey David thank you for the tip! there is no actual error message in this scenario but i will keep it in mind goinf forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Docker Hub `mongo` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), and click on "Tags" and then `latest`, you'll get an automatically extracted dump of the image's build steps.  That in particular has a line

```
VOLUME [/data/db /data/configdb]
```

Since the image declares these two directories as `VOLUME`, Docker will always mount some sort of volume on them, creating an anonymous volume if nothing else is specified.  There is [no way to "un-VOLUME" a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976184/docker-base-image-includes-a-volume-how-can-i-stop-mounting-it-in-my-derived-im).  If you're concerned about leaking the anonymous volumes and want to track them, you could add a second named volume for that directory, even if you're not directly using it.

Comment: I knew there must've been another volume I was missing! Thank you David, this solved it for me